# Android Jetpack LeadingIconTab Composable how to have icon above text centered?

Tags: android, kotlin, composable

```
LeadingIconTab(
            icon = { Icon(painter = painterResource(id = tab.icon), contentDescription = "") },
            text = { Text(tab.title) },
            selected = pagerState.currentPage == index,
            onClick = {
                scope.launch {
                    pagerState.scrollToPage(index)
                }
            },
        )
```

I do NOT want his layout:
[image]

I WANT this please? but how?
[image]

https://material.io/components/tabs

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Tab` Composable instead of `LeadingIconTab`:

```
   Tab(selected = true, onClick = { /*TODO*/ } , text = { Text(text = "Hello") }, icon = {
            Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_home_24), contentDescription = "Home Picture")})
```